# How does restorecon handle links?

Tags: symlink, selinux, hard-link

I noticed that the rule

```
/usr/sbin/shutdown  --  gen_context(system_u:object_r:shutdown_exec_t,s0)
```

labels `/usr/sbin/shutdown` `shutdown_exec_t` when `/usr/sbin` is a directory. But it doesn't restore the same label when `/usr/sbin` is a symbolic link to `bin` and `shutdown` is in `/usr/bin`. Why? If `/usr/sbin` is a symbolic link to `bin`, is there an easy way to give the files that are supposed to be in `/usr/sbin` the correct contexts?

It looks like that if an inode has 2 hard links to it, and the paths have different default file contexts, the resulting file context will differ depending on which path is given to `restorecon`. What context will it have if I relabel the whole filesystem? Is it deterministic? Is it ok or good to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`restorecon` doesn't **handle** symbolic links just the way it handles files.  According to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/restorecon) (a little old, so useful as a starting point):

> **Note**
>   restorecon does not follow symbolic links.

This was observed in a bug report, [Bug 825221: restorecon disregards custom rules for sym links](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825221), with these pertinent comments:

- [Daniel Walsh 2012-05-29 13:54:13 EDT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825221#c3)

  > We just fixed this in F17.
- [Daniel Walsh 2012-08-15 14:01:52 EDT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825221#c13)

  > restorecon is doing a realpath on the file, so it is translating the file via realpath.  We are doing this so that a symbolic link attack will not cause the file to get mislabeled.
- [Karel Srot 2012-08-23 06:14:05 EDT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825221#c17)

  > Just tested this on RHEL6.3 and Fedora 17.
  >
  > On RHEL6 restorecon doesn't restore the context of the symlink (when symlink is the actual item). On Fedora 17 the context is restored. I belive this is the problem mentioned in #c6.
  >
  > Dan, could you please confirm that this is what's is going to be fixed? Thank you.
- [Miroslav Grepl 2012-08-23 09:59:41 EDT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=825221#c20)

  > Ok, we discovered bug in the policy. We do not have the following rule on RHEL6
  >
  > `allow setfiles_t file_type : lnk_file { read getattr relabelfrom relabelto } ;`
  >
  > We have just
  >
  > `allow setfiles_t file_type : lnk_file { getattr relabelfrom relabelto } ;`
  >
  > So I am switching this bug to `selinux-policy` component.

Somewhat later (2015), in [Some questions about using restorecon on symlink](http://seandroid-list.tycho.nsa.narkive.com/aoGRhuQy/some-questions-about-using-restorecon-on-symlink) , Stephen Smalley commented

> Yes, they resolve to different inodes (a symbolic link is its own
>   file/inode in Linux, separate and independent of the target). *The
>   symbolic link SELinux label only controls access to the symlink (i.e.
>   the ability to unlink, rename, or read it), not access to its target
>   (which is controlled based on the target's label).*

So... barring some further rule, the **symbolic links** are (mostly) irrelevant to the permissions on the **target** that you're concerned about.

Comment: Is there an easy way to give the files that are supposed to be in `/usr/sbin` the correct contexts if `/usr/sbin` is a symbolic link to `bin`?