# podman fails with 'Error relocating' / 'RELRO protection failed'; ~/.local/share/containers a link to a different location

Tags: selinux, container, podman

Trying to run any pods on Podman fails, after an SELinux relabeling

```
$ podman run -ti alpine
Error relocating /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1: RELRO protection failed: No error information
Error relocating /bin/sh: RELRO protection failed: No error information
```

And you have moved your `~/.local/share/containers` elsewhere, linking there:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/share/containers
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 asdf asdf 32 Oct 13  2022 /home/asdf/.local/share/containers -> /x/y/z/containers/
```

On the audit logs, an AVC alert will be logged

Answer (score 0):

## Root cause

SELinux' `semanage fcontext` database deals with realpaths [1].  If you moved your `~/.local/share/containers` elsewhere (in my case, to manage disk space) and created a link to it, when `restorecon` runs, it will will reset its labels to whatever the real location corresponds to (most probably `default_t`).

You can check that with [2]:

```
ls -Z ~/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay{,-images,-layers} | less
```

The files should have an SELinux context of `container_ro_file_t`.  You'll be able to see the original `semanage fcontext` rules with the following command:

```
# semanage fcontext -l | grep container | grep storage
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-images(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-layers(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay2(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay2-images(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/overlay2-layers(/.*)? all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_ro_file_t:s0 
/home/[^/]+/\.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/[^/]*/.* all files          unconfined_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0
```

## Fix

You'll have to copy and adapt each of the rules to your environment.  For example, for the first line above:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t container_ro_file_t '/x/y/z/containers/storage/overlay(/.*)?'
```

Of course, replace `/x/y/z` with your environment's location and execute the command for each of the original rules.  Make sure to use your system's original rules as the source of truth, as it may differ from mine.

Pay attention that the `volumes` line is slightly different from the rest.

Once all rules are in place, run `restorecon`:

```
restorecon -Rv /x/y/z/containers/
```

I'm not sure whether this is the best or most correct way to go about this, and it may not be supported.  But creating that link in the first place is already a deviation, in any case.  And it did work for me :)

## References

- [1] [How does restorecon handle links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303331/how-does-restorecon-handle-links)
- [2] https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/2025

Answer (score 0):

The posted response (by caxcaxcoatl) is on point.

I found perhaps a more straightforward solution for this:

```
for item in $(ls -Z ~/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay{,-images,-layers} | grep home | sed 's/://g')
do
   sudo restorecon -Rv ${item}
done
```